# Почему не работает youtube_dl disnake?

Tags: бот, discord, discord.py

```
from disnake.ext import commands
```

from disnake import Client, FFmpegPCMAudio
import asyncio
import youtube_dl

class MusicCog(commands.Cog):
def **init**(self, bot: Client):
self.bot = bot
self.voice_clients = {}
self.yt_dl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio/best'}
self.ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(self.yt_dl_opts)
self.ffmpeg_options = {'options': "-vn"}

```
@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx, url: str):
    try:
        voice_client = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
        self.voice_clients[voice_client.guild.id] = voice_client
    except:
        print("Ошибочка")

    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: self.ytdl.extract_info(url, download=False))
        song = data['url']
        player = FFmpegPCMAudio(song, **self.ffmpeg_options, executable="C:\\Frezee\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe")

        self.voice_clients[ctx.guild.id].play(player)

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```

def setup(bot):
print('Module Music is loaded')
bot.add_cog(MusicCog(bot))

> [youtube] UoP6zDAC-9o: Downloading webpage
> ERROR: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see https://yt-dl.org/update on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
> ERROR: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see https://yt-dl.org/update on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

обновление не помогает!